# If $f(x)$ continuous in $[0,1]$ then $\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}f\left(\sin x\right)dx=\:\int _0^{\frac{\pi \:}{2}}f\left(\cos x\right)dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

It's easy with if we substitude $x=\frac{\pi }{2}-t$ then $dx=-dt$

And therfore $\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}f\left(\sin x\right)dx=-\int _{\frac{\pi }{2}}^0f\left(\sin \left(\frac{\pi }{2}-t\right)\right)dt=\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}f\left(\cos \left(t\right)\right)dt$

That's it. easy with substitude.
But is there any other straightforward way to show this without using substitude ?

Comment: substitute is the easiest way. another way is to show that there is a bijection between the values sin(x) and cos(x) gets in $[0,\pi/2]$

Comment: You can see the graphs of the functions to directly get the result